# VGA Display problem in my custom OS kernel

Tags: c, assembly, x86, osdev, vga

I am developing an Operating System as a hobby project. I interfaced VGA display by using address 0xB8000, and number of rows are set to 25, and columns are set to 80. I have used following clear screen function :

```
void vga_init(void) {

    // Initialise the VGA variables and clear the screen : :
    vga_buffer_pointer = (uint16_t *)  VGA_MEMORY_LOCATION;

    //start clear using 2 pass loop : 
    uint8_t iter_i = 0;
    uint8_t iter_j = 0;

    for(iter_i = 0; iter_i < VGA_ROWS; iter_i ++) {

        for(iter_j = 0; iter_j < VGA_COLS; iter_j++) {
            uint8_t index  = (VGA_COLS *  iter_i) + iter_j;

            vga_buffer_pointer[index] = ((uint16_t)color << 8) | ' ';
        }
    }

    enable_cursor(14,15);
}
```

I am initialising the screen with green color. The display occupies only a porting of the qemu terminal screen, As shown below :

[image: a busy cat]

But I want, the entire terminal to be green. And the display should use the entire terminal. Any help is most appreciated. Thank you

I have attached a gist of my code.

[VGA.c](https://gist.github.com/Narasimha1997/fa8d3882af3ff61e77aefa5309e9a78d)

Comment: Yes! I am using i686 cross compiler and specifying option as -m32

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing uint8_t to uint16_t worked! I was debugging it from past 2 days and I did not take care of it! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: please do not post links to code.  Rather copy/paste the code into your question

Comment: @user3629249 : He pasted the relevant code.The screenshot indicates what the incorrect output looks like (in the QEMU Window). In this case I found the visual very useful to establish the type of bug it likely was. It is harder to express colors or appearance of failures without a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
uint8_t index = (VGA_COLS * iter_i) + iter_j;
```

to:

```
uint16_t index = (VGA_COLS * iter_i) + iter_j;
```

A `uint8_t` isn't big enough to hold the calculation for the index so it is being truncated causing only part of the display to be erased.

Comment: Thank you so much ! And it is a great remainder for everyone , we have to take care of word lengths and signed bits while coding OS kernels ! :p